# Deleting files is slow

Tags: 2013, delete

I noticed recently that when I delete files or list items (1 or 50) it takes about 1-2 minutes to process. Also, if I delete multiple files it times out and some files are not deleted.

Has anyone had this issue?
I am a Site Collection Admin and we are launching a new SP2013 Intranet next week.

Comment: how many items in the list(total)?

Comment: It can range from 1 to 300 items and/or files.

Comment: in past we had an issue where a complex library(with alot of lookups & person etc columns) and 50k+ items. when ever we try to delete a single file it takes couple of min. what is your farm structure?

Comment: It's pretty standard. 1 farm 1 site. We do have a lookup field on each doc. Uploading is not a problem.

Comment: try to create a standard libary without lookups and then test it.

Comment: I tried several OOTB lists and libraries. No luck. Still takes a looooong time to delete.

Comment: try to use powershell instead if you want to delete in large amount. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89200/sharepoint-doc-library-batch-delete

Comment: But my problem is when the average user wants to delete ONE file it takes a couple of minutes. I can't have 1200 people using powershell.

Comment: Hi MrRCG, you need to re-design your list by implementing index http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/cc262813(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: have you try this: http://www.aasoftech.com/Demo/SitePages/Delete-Bulk-SharePoint-List-Items.aspx